# HTML2FO not working in BI Publisher to convert HTML stored in CLOB to rendered HTML in RTF

Tags: bi-publisher, xml-publisher

I'v using BI Publisher Desktop Template Viewer, and BI Publisher Enterprise to render HTML stored in the database as formatted HTML, and I'm not getting any output for the HTML field when using `html2fo`

I'm storing HTML in a CLOB field in the database.

To select into the XML I'm using something like this per [Oracle's documentation](https://blogs.oracle.com/xmlpublisher/html-in-xml-support):

```
SELECT '<![CDATA' || '['||  CLOB1  || ']' || ']>' as HTML
FROM TABLE1
```

I'm getting what I expect in the XML output. Field has the CDATA wrapper, and is HTML.

I've tried this in my RTF and output for that field is blank.

```
<?html2fo: HTML?>
```

I've also tried these, no difference.

```
<?HTML2FO: HTML?> --function in upper case
<?HTML2FO:HTML?> --no space, function in upper case
<?html2fo:HTML?> --no space, function in lower case
```

When I just used this, I see the raw CDATA/HTML

```
<?HTML?>
```

Any idea what I could be doing wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: Your HTML code could be wrong.

Comment: You can test if your HTML2FO is working with something like `<?HTML2FO:’&#37;’?>`

Comment: I narrowed down the problem to the CDATA addition. I'm only using this because of Oracle's own documentation. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong then.. I followed their guidelines. I fear if I skip the CDATA step, it will fail at some point if someone enters some < or > characters into the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option/setting for CLOB fields in the data diagram, when configuring the how the data is selected. Default option is CLOB, and the other option is XML.

Different versions of BI Publisher will display this option differently. Here is from Oracle documentation, and then from the version I'm using.

[image]
[image]

If CLOB is selected, the data will be HTML escaped, and tags will change from `<` to `&lt;`

**Option 1** 
Keep the CLOB type, and remove the CDATA tag insertion from the select statement.

**Option 2**
Change to XML type, and keep the CDATA tag insertion in the select statement.